# Android requiring 64 bit versions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Android announced the following:
(https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html)

> Starting August 1, 2019:
>
> - All new apps and app updates that include native code are required to provide 64-bit versions in addition to 32-bit versions when publishing to Google Play.
> - Extension: Google Play will continue to accept 32-bit only updates to existing games that use Unity 5.6.x or older until August 2021.

My team develops using Xamarin. In that selecting the architecture for 64 (in addition to 32) is all we have to do? (See below image)

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit and verify you have a 64-bit binary?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/64-bit-requirements-xamarin-android-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rainmaker [this article](https://medium.com/@prototypemakers/64-bit-version-of-your-xamarin-native-or-xamarin-forms-android-app-477d0e637432) also has a video of how to do just that

You just have to go to your Android project options, the Click on build settings.
Click on the Advanced tab and Change the configuration to Release and make sure that the “arm64-v8a” ABI is supported. Press OK and you are done.

Comment: fantastic. Thanks  a lot